# Removing inline styling from fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I use FancyBox 2, and I want to edit inline style and I want to remove `display: block;` from `fancybox-overlay`.

original:

```
<div class="fancybox-overlay fancybox-overlay-fixed" style="width: auto; height: auto; display: block;">
```

edited:

```
<div class="fancybox-overlay fancybox-overlay-fixed" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I erase all inline styles with javascript and leave only the styles specified in the css style sheet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229688/how-can-i-erase-all-inline-styles-with-javascript-and-leave-only-the-styles-spec)

Comment: If your remove `display: block;` property from `fancybox-overlay fancybox-overlay-fixed`, the entire fancybox will disappear. What is exactly the purpose of this? or what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
$('.fancybox-overlay.fancybox-overlay-fixed').css('display', '')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fancybox-overlay fancybox-overlay-fixed" style="width: auto; height: auto; display:block;">No display Block</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want inline you must do it always when it will be shown...
The better way is remove it in CSS

```
.fancybox-overlay.fancybox-overlay-fixed { display: inline!important; }
```

But if you need inline version you can always take action to the event beforeShow:

```js
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
   beforeShow: function() {
     $('.fancybox-overlay.fancybox-overlay-fixed').css('display', '')
   }
});
```